# Is a subcompact space submetacompact?

Tags: general-topology

Is a subcompact space  submetacompact?

The space is subcompact if it has a base $\mathcal B$ such that every regular filterbase $\mathcal U \subset \mathcal B$ has non-empty intersection. This definition can be seen from this paper:http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864113001533

Thanks for any help!